# Need advice to improve response on click button

Tags: android, android-widget

Need advice for AsyncTask. I have inside my activity private class which extends AsyncTask and I in doInBackground create new AsyncTask and repeat that all time ( parse JSON and update some labels on screen). Problem is that I have bad response on buttons when I click on  them, so I need advice how to improve response on click ( when I click button is green and that is couple seconds  before starts action ). Do I need to put Thread.sleep in doInBackground  or there is some better way to improve  ?

Comment: Try removing the private part from your inner class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not create a new AsyncTask inside doInBackground. instead, perform some kind of loop (depends on your code). If you create multiple instances of AsyncTask (one inside another) you create way too many threads and make the UI thread much more busy too.

Comment: I do it in onPostExecute so I don't create new threads, I think, because one die another create and so on...

Comment: It's not what you wrote... please re-phrase the question